# por que se cambia el estilo cuando lo subo a un hosting?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

asi se ve en mi servidor local
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y asi se ve cuando lo subo al hosting
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es el codigo del login

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Ingresar</title>
    <!-- Mobile Specific Metas -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <!-- Font-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/nunito-font.css">
    <!-- Main Style Css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mystyle.css"/>
</head>
<body class="form-v6">
    <div class="page-content">
        <div class="form-v6-content">
            <div class="form-left">
                <img src="images/form-v8.jpg" alt="form">
            </div>
            <form id="form1" class="form-detail" action="ingresar.php" method="post">
                <h2>Ingresar</h2>
                
        <br>
        <br>
                <div class="form-row">
                    <input type="text" name="txtEmailL" id="txtEmailL" class="input-text" placeholder="Correo" required pattern="[^@]+@[^@]+.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}">
                </div>
                <div class="form-row">
                    <input type="password" name="txtContraseñaL" id="txtContraseñaL" class="input-text" placeholder="Contraseña" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-row-last">
                    <input type="submit" name="register" class="register" value="Ingresar">
                </div>
        <p style="text-align: right"><a href="register.html">Registrarse</a></p>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

no se si es por los links que uso para el estilo o por la ubicacion de los css pero no entiendo porque si tienen la misma ubicacion en el hosting

Comment: Tu hosting tiene certificado SSL? Cuando cargues la página, con CONTROL + U abres el código fuente (front) en una nueva pestaña, desde ahí, intenta abrir los enlaces referentes a CSS (es decir: css/mystyle.css), mira si te carga el código CSS, que no sea un problema de certificados de seguridad. Si te carga todo correcto, vuelve a tu pagina principal y refresca

Answer (score 1):

En primer lugar veo que las imágenes que nos has dejado son de dos páginas distintas (en tu server local es la página de acceso y en el server remoto es la página de registro)

Además, veo que en la línea donde llamas al estilo principal, cierras la etiqueta `link` con `/>`, mientras que en la línea donde llamas al estilo de las fuentes sola la cierras con `>`. Según parece por las imágenes el estilo de las fuentes sí te lo está respetando, y, en principio, esta cuestión del cierre de la etiqueta no debería influir en nada, pero el cierre con `/>` creo que es propio de HTML 4, y no de HTML 5 que es el estándar actual. Prueba a ver a cambiarlo por si acaso tu servidor no soportara bien HTML 4

Comment: Que se vea registro no creo que influya en nada, he visto varias veces esa plantilla de login, cuando no se cargan correctamente los archivos JS o CSS, se daña la vista inicial (que es 1 sola, registro e inicio de sesion).